# How to get messages from googles Pub/Sub sytsem by using the current pubsub subsciber

Tags: python-3.x, subscription, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to receive published messages from googles Pub/Sub system by using a python based subscriber.

For this I did the following steps:

- On the web console I created a project, a registry, a telemetry topic, a device and attached a subscription topic to the telemtry topic
- A the Moment my code can publish messages over the mqtt bridge and also the publish functionality of the pubsub library
- I can pull this messages over the terminal by using the following cmd:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --auto-ack projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{subscription_topic}
```

In the following you see the important snippet of my code. It is based on the git-examples but some functions do not seem to exist anymore in version **0.39.1** of the **google-cloud-pubsub** package. One example is the subscriber.subscription_path() method.

```
def receive_messages(subscription_path, service_account_json):
    import time
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=service_account_json)

    #subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
    #   project_id, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
        message.ack()

    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

    print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
```

When I run this function, countless threads are started in the background bit by bit, but none of them seem to ever quit or start the callback function.

- I hopefully installed all requirements:

```
pip3 freeze

asn1crypto==0.24.0
cachetools==3.0.0
certifi==2018.11.29
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.4.2
google-api-core==1.7.0
google-api-python-client==1.7.5
google-auth==1.6.2
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.8.1
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.3
google-cloud-monitoring==0.31.1
google-cloud-pubsub==0.39.1
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.6
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.11.4
grpcio==1.17.1
httplib2==0.12.0
idna==2.8
keyring==10.1
keyrings.alt==1.3
oauthlib==3.0.0
paho-mqtt==1.4.0
protobuf==3.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.3
pycparser==2.19
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
pygobject==3.22.0
PyJWT==1.6.4
python-apt==1.4.0b3
pytz==2018.9
pyxdg==0.25
redis==3.0.1
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
RPi.GPIO==0.6.5
rsa==4.0
SecretStorage==2.3.1
six==1.12.0
unattended-upgrades==0.1
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.24.1
virtualenv==16.2.0
```

- I run that code on debian aswell on windows 10 and updated the gcloud:

```
gcloud components update
```

For the past week, I've been trying different solutions out of the way or starting the seemingly obsolete google examples. Also, the documentation, which seems even older than the code examples did not help with. So I hope someone here can help me to finally receive python-based client messages via the Pub/Sub-Sytsem.

I hope I could provide the most important information and thank you in advance for your effort to help me.

Comment: Maybe this help your https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python

Comment: Hello Tamir,
Thanks for your help, but unfortunately I already know this repository and have already tried to keep to their examples described there, but unfortunately it resulted in exactly the same behavior. I started to dubscribe to an previously created topic and after that an infinitely number of threads starts in the background put no messages are received and no callback functions for the messages are called. But if i use the gcloud tool i can subscribe an receive the messages under the same topic.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The examples maintained on the python documentation site [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/) should be up to date.  Make sure that you've followed all the steps in the "In order to use this library, you first need to go through the following steps" section before running any code.  In particular, you may not have properly set up authentication, I don't believe you should be passing the credentials path manually.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
thank you very much for your help.

Of course, the steps listed under "In order to use this library, you first need to go through the following steps" are followed. I can also publish and subscribe using "Cloud Tools for PowerShell" below.

# Publish:
gcloud pubsub topics publish projects / {project_id} / topics / {topic_id} --message = "Test Message"

# Pull subscirbe:
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --auto-ack projects / {project_id} / subscriptions / {subscription_id}

Comment: I have created a subscriber client and a public client as described in the following documentation:
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/

# The publisher client will hang indefinitely in the "Thread-MonitorBatchPublisher" generated after calling "future = publisher.publish" (topic_name, b'My first message !, "spam = 'eggs')" without ever posting a message publish.

Comment: # The subscriber client either remains in the function "subscription_respond = subscriber.create_subscription () for an infinite time
    name = subscription_name, topic = topic_name) "hang or start without this function over future = subscriber.subscribe (subscription_name, callback) infinite many tasks in the background without ever calling the callback.

Comment: Quick question: You said that the above is the "important section" of your code.  At any point in the other sections of you code are you creating a subprocess using multiprocessing?  Forking is [known](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16001) to cause grpc to hang.  My other advice would be to ensure there are messages outstanding in your backlog after you've created the subscription so there is something for the subscriber to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
print(f"Received {message}.")
message.ack()

streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, 
callback=callback)
print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")


try:

    streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
except TimeoutError:
    streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
    streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).